Have any 2-bit or 3-bit computers ever been designed?
Computers can work with as little as 1 bit of data at a time, have only 1 instruction, and 1-bit RAM was once common. A big step up, 4-bit architectures were very versatile, including the famous Intel 4004. IBM has built itself on 6-bit computers.
We've gone mostly up since then, with 64-bit ISA and 512-bit vectors now standard, through tensor computing and ML have resurrected 4-bit integers and 6-bit floating point numbers as preferred for efficiency and throughput.
2-bit, 3-bit and other odd counts are missing, though even ternary has been tried. Yes, they're not very useful - this is about history, not utility. So, useful or not, has anyone prototyped or seriously proposed designs that made significant use of 2-bit or 3-bit architectural features?

Does Intel 3000 family chips count if you use them to implement only a 2-bit processor? Or bit-serial processors?

@Justme I'd draw the line for seriously proposed at someone having invested time or money into it, with expectations of improving something compared to then-existing CPUs. We know arbitrary n-bit CPU are possible.

Heh I was going to suggest the Intel 3000 as well, as kind of a joke.  It's not a standalone microprocessor.  But the last sentence of the question is "Has anyone prototyped or seriously proposed designs that made significant use of 2-bit or 3-bit architectural features?" and it has to be said that any design built on the Intel 3000 series would definitely have made "significant use of 2-bit architectural features" ....

1-bit makes sense if you do serial processing, for theoretical purposes, or for embedded controllers; and you simulate larger values serially. 2 or 3 bits don't really allow enough values to do anything interesting, and they are not different from "n" bits, so I'd assume for practical purposes the smallest variant implemented is 4-bit (also as building blocks in bit-sllice CPUs etc.).

@dirkt I suppose Intel 3002 in fact counts as an answer, but ideally one would have to find a real design using it that way. What for? Well, that's why it's a question, not a proposal.

@Therac The 3002 was intended to be used as a bit slice, so an actual design like this floppy controller would have many of them (here: 4x 3002 for 8 bits). Other bit-slice ALUs had typically 4-bit, this seems to have only 2-bit because lots of pins are used for muxed inputs (M, I, K) and there's two latched outputs (A, D), and back then, the number of pins on DIP packages was limited. If you look at the list, there's only one other 2-bit slice.

@Therac A bit slice is not a processor or computer but a logic element akin to an ALU with buffered output and a register. The 3002 being 2 bit is mostly due use of an 28 pin device. Also 2 is the only divider common to 4 and 6, which was still a thing in 1973 thinking.  Other elements of that 'kit' feature different sizes or no relation to word size.

TL;DR: No, as they do not add value
Using 2 or 3 bit data width does neither allow handling of an additional fundamental data type, nor does it save wireing.


Computers can work with as little as 1 bit of data at a time,

Err, not really as next to all 'one bit at a time' computers (*1) were serial implementations of parallel architectures. They operated on longer words at once - like 12 bit with the PDP-8s - but one bit at a time to save components.

have only 1 instruction,

Which is rather a gedankenexperiment than a real implementation - TTA based implementation of special controllers may be seen as the exception.

and 1-bit RAM was once common.

Which is is due the fact that it hit's several goals at once at it features the

most simple internal structure, needs the
least amount of pins needed, thus
allowing most compact package, while still
enable arbitrary word size, all at a
lowest possible price point.


A big step up, 4-bit architectures were very versatile, including the famous Intel 4004.

As it is the first size that adds a new fundamental data type:
A BCD digit.
Most notably a good idea for the 4004 as it was intended to power a desktop calculator, which inherently has to handle decimal digits as its basic data type.

IBM has built itself on 6-bit computers.

Many manufacturers used 6 Bit and multiples thereof (*2) as word size, as it allows (almost) direct manipulation of another fundamental data typ:
An Alpha-Numeric Character
All based on the fact that character codes used in very early computers were 6 bit and (mostly) based on teletype code sets. Thus doing 6 bit at a time (or a multiple thereof) greatly advanced native handling of text.

2-bit, 3-bit and other odd counts are conspicuously missing,

Well, there are of course 9/18 bit which thank their existence the availability of cheap 18/36 bit core memory modules :) Same goes for 12 bit based comparably cheap on 12 bit core. Either size was first used large number with mainframes thus becoming lower priced over time - plus another boost when mainframes switched for dedicated high performance modules (*3).

though even ternary has been tried.

Which isn't about data size, but fundamental computing scheme.

Has anyone prototyped or seriously proposed designs that made significant use of 2-bit or 3-bit architectural features?

As mentioned it does not make any sense:

Not from an engineering perspective, as 2 or 3 bit words add all hassles of multi bit operation while not giving much performance boost.
Neither from a computing perspective. A two or three bit will not give a new data type. Any program using a 2 bit CPU will have the same issues and code aford to handle higher data types, like decimal digit or character, as a 1 bit CPU (looping, etc.). A 4, 6 or 8 bit CPU in turn does not only deliver more performance, but also can handle those important data types without ponderous programming, allowing a more concrete programming.


*1 - That is excluding oddities like the MC14550, more a bit slice (although missing signals for widening up) than a CPU, intended as core building block to create solid state ladder logic.
*2 - Not sure which machines you mean, as the 1401 used a variable word length with a basic memory capable of addressing 7 bit bytes (plus parity). The 1620 on the other hand used 6 bit bytes, but stored as 12 to 72 bit words, accessed and processed as such. So which is the 6 bit computer you're referring to?
*3 - That's also the reason why there was no 6 bit micro processor. by the time micros became a thing core was long gone and thus the need to optimize/align to those sizes.

Just a nit: The 1620 didn't have words. It had variable length fields built up of decimal digits (as you said, represented 6bits each). Min field length was 2 digits, max field length could be as large as you wanted - except that you had to also fit your program and all your other data into memory. (Min length two because you needed room for both the digit that had the "end of field" flag (most significant digit) and the digit that had the "negative number" flag (on the least significant digit) - and since both flags use the same flag bit that was part of every digit they had to be different.

You might have been referring to the storage being two digits wide (12 bits) but I don't think arithmetic was done that way - at least in the Model I arithmetic was done with a table looked up in memory and that table was only 10 x 10 digits long - so at least in the Model I arithmetic was one digit by digit.  Also - now I think of it - your fields could be an odd number of digits long - if arithmetic was done in pairs-of-digits the way memory was arranged there would have been special circuitry to handle the odd lengths.   (Maybe there's more information elsewhere?)

@davidbak I might not be as much of an expert as you, but I did play more than a few hours with 1401 and 1620. Also, I would think that footnote *2 does reflect all you mentioned - 6 bit bytes, individual addressable, variable word length and fixed size memory interface of at least two digits (At least I tried to be clear). The point here is that he asks a quite global question while at the same time allowing partial features being the answer - in case of the 1620 the 12 bit (for the smallest model) memory interface is such a feature.

An important use case of these early 4bits CPUs was pocket calculators and stuff that uses decimal numbers, for example a digital weighting scale. ( for example TI TMS 1000, HP Saturn)
They didn't need to be fast, a multiplication could last tens of milliseconds as long as it is low power, but they had to handle decimal numbers, and 3 bits registers isn't quite enough.

This doesn't seem to address whether anyone designed a 2- or 3-bit processor.

@dave It explains why 4 bits are considered necessary (to be able to store a decimal digit)

It could be made to fit the question by being arranged to explictly fit the narrative '4 bit CPUs were implemented early on for application in calculators; given that they existed, there was no use-case where a 2 or 3 bit CPU would offer an improvement', which I think is the point intended by this answer.

Those examples were from a long line of BCD computers (going back to ENIAC), they're really 3.4-bit processors.
